# How can I plot two lines from two columns of Data frame and scale the y axis using ggplot package

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, ggplotly

I am trying to compare the values of two columns of my data frame. I would like to use ggplot and plot two lines that indicates all values in first column are greater than the second column.

Here is my df:

```
C1 <- c(-1.363953,4.265514,5.609484,7.524796,2.562210,7.214769, 4.667354,4.950837,4.134733,7.540626)
C2 <- c(-1.541836,4.248582,5.557042,7.475255,2.424585,7.125046,4.524404  4.890195,3.945435,7.488123)
C3 <- seq(1:10)
Name <- paste(letters[1:10])
df <- data.frame(Name = paste(letters[1:10]), C1, C2,C3)


Name        C1        C2.     C3
 a      -1.363953   -1.541836  1
 b       4.265514    4.248582  2
 c       5.609484    5.557042  3
 d       7.524796    7.475255  4
 e       2.562210    2.424585  5
 f       7.214769    7.125046  6
 g       4.667354    4.524404  7
 h       4.950837    4.890195  8
 i       4.134733    3.945435  9
 j       7.540626    7.488123 10
```

First I am transposing the data.
    tt <- t(df)
here is my command to plot the values:

```
 matplot(x<- 1:10, cbind(tt[2,],tt[3,]),type="l",col=c("red","green"),lty=c(1,1))
```

Since the values are very close I cannot see the difference very clearly in plot. 
[image]

I would like to use ggplot function and scale the y axis so that I can see the difference of the two lines better.

Do you have any idea how can I do this? 
Thanks

Comment: What's missing in the 3rd line of the code you added as example?

Comment: If the difference is the important thing, why don’t you plot that? Instead of 2 linear, have 1 line that’s C1-C2. That will make the difference much clearer, especially since the difference is tiny relative to the actual values

Answer (score 2):

You can use `scale_y_continuous()` with the limits argument in ggplot. If just for plotting purposes, there is no need to transpose. Given the difference between your two lines, and the total span of the data points on the y-axis, you will never really be able to make the difference between them easier to see without losing some data points though. You could try with different colour lines or line types on a different colour background to make the difference more visible?

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = C3, y = C1))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(2.4,7.7))+
  geom_line(aes(x = C3, y = C1),colour = "red")+
  geom_line(aes(x = C3, y = C2),colour = "green")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you think using gather() and use bar plots would be helpful to see the difference of the values in 2 columns ?

Comment: I don't know, I've never used it, sorry. You could consider plotting the differences between C1 and C2, i.e x = C3 and y = (C2-C1), if the original values aren't as important as the difference?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @divibisan , if the difference is important then you should consider plotting only the difference which will make it more clear to see the exact distinction.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  mutate(diff = C1 - C2) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(factor(C3), diff, group = 1) + geom_line()
```

[image]

You can also use `geom_point()` but I think `geom_line()` conveys it better.

---

Or using base plotting.

```
df$diff <- df$C1 - df$C2
plot(df$C3, df$diff, type = "l")
```